# Votes reported on reputation tab don't match votes shown on the post

Tags: support, profile-page, down-votes, reputation-history

A question in my reputation tab shows two downvotes, and my reputation total reflects this:

[image: screen shot]

However, the question itself shows only one downvote:

[image: screen shot]

The downvotes were cast several hours ago, so I don't think I should blame caching.

What's going on?

Comment: Well, my guess is that the same person downvoted twice using a sock, then they got merged, or the sock nuked, but the reputation event in history somehow "stuck" there.

Comment: I don't have any "voting reversed" or "user was removed" events, for what that's worth.  (I don't know what trails are left for merges.)

Comment: I know, hence likely a merge, which leaves both votes in the Votes table, by two different users. The reputation recalc is smart enough to detect they're now the same, however reputation history just read without performing those validations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when someone casts a spam/offensive flag on your post which ends up getting declined. The automatic downvote(s) against you by the Community user get invalidated immediately and your reputation corrected, but for some reason it doesn't remove the downvote event from your reputation history.

The system corrects this on its own via a process that runs at 03:00 UTC that removes "phantom" events which shouldn't exist from your reputation history.

Comment: Any chance this will be fixed? (i.e. any point retagging as [tag:bug])

Comment: @Fiksdal I am not sure, that's why I asked. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, I must confess that my real plan was to ping animuson.

Comment: @Fiksdal well, it's not rare for the team to ignore comments. I learned to accept this. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Can't blame them. I'm sure they get a fair amount of pings each day.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm kind of on the fence. Considering it fixes itself within 24 hours, it's certainly not a high priority. But this kind of auto-downvote doesn't behave like a normal downvote, so we can't just slap an unupvote event onto the reputation history and let it handle it that way. In this case we always completely remove the original event as if it never happened, which requires a full recalc to do. So even if declining the flag scheduled the user for recalc, the profile would still be inaccurate for up to 15 minutes, which is still enough time for some people to notice.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the explanation, even if a bit belated. :-) /cc @Fiksdal